# Dell and preinstalled McAfee. Uninstalling it is causing Issues with Windows security. Why?

Tags: security, windows-11, anti-virus

I am using Dell. I have recently reset my PC. After reinstalling Windows 11, it also pre-installed McAfee antivirus, (I'd not consented to this). After uninstalling, I cannot see or make any changes to Windows security screen. It is blank.

[image: Error Message]

I have tried following

1. Resetting Windows 11 again. But causes the same issue, as it always pre-install McAfee
2. Resetting Windows Security App
3. Removing McAfee with its removal tool
4. Registry tweaks, but it is empty under Windows Defender

I am running Windows 11 home edition with full administrative access.

Comment: Stop using the OEM Windows 11 image. Download a Windows 11 ISO, from the Microsoft website, mount the ISO from within Windows and run setup.exe. That particular message has little to do with McAfee though

Comment: FWIW, I did the exact same thing with the exact same result. I've tried everything; guides, registry hacks, you name it. No dice. Dell really did a good job with this one.

Comment: @Ramhound They play this psychological trick on you where you're led to believe that the OS image specifically tailored for your machine by the manufacturer is somehow better suited than official stock. Gets me every time. As for McAfee's role in this, their software removal tool leaves Windows Security in this broken, unfixable state.

Comment: Everything broken is fixable in my opinion, but the author didn’t provide the information, necessary to walk through that process